# Why did black lines appear on my image cr ated by pen tool?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Why does my image have black lines? This is created using pen tool and I'm using Illustrator.

Comment: welcome to GD.SE. Can you expand your question to explain exactly what is the problem, what did you try that didn't work? Perhaps with screenshots? If you want to know more about the site, please see [help]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Yes- please provide an example of what you are seeing and the steps you took to produce. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you enabled outline mode. This is a mode that will break your image/design down to simple black lines, where you can see everything (even if it's behind an object). Commonly referred to as "outline or wireframe". You can toggle this view by pressing `CMD + Y`(Mac) or `CTRL + Y`(Windows) or `View > Outline` in the top application toolbar.

This is an example of a design in `normal view` and `outline view`
[image: Original and Outline View]